# WebClient HTML Unit driver is not working

Tags: java, selenium

I am new in using `WebClient HtmlUnitDriver`. I am using *htmlunit-2.10.jar* file in build path in Eclipse, below is the code..

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getPage("https://www.google.co.in");
```

I am getting below error :

```
****Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet**
```

Please let me know how this can be solved, an answer will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebClient` has nothing to do with your error:

See if you use a `ListOrderSet` object in your code. 
If you do, try to import the right package, for example. Mine is:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.set.ListOrderedSet;
```

See this [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/set/ListOrderedSet.html) for more info on the `ListOrderSet`;

Answer (score 0):

try to set these options tour client object

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
try {
  client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
  client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
  client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

  WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(new URL(REST_URL), methodCall);
```

And kindly upgrade to never version as it is available e.g  to 2.13